# How to Alter table with updating FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, mariadb, foreign-keys

I am new in data base phpmyadmin
Here my query that is giving error

```
ALTER TABLE students
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_enrollment_student
FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES enrollments (student_id);
```

Here are structure of my table

**Table: students**
[image]

**Table: enrollments**
[image]

**Table: courses**
[image]
It is giving this error

> SQL Query Console Console
> ascendingdescendingOrder:Debug SQLExecution orderTime takenOrder by:Group queries
> Some error occurred while getting SQL debug info.
> OptionsSet default
> Always expand query messages
> Show query history at start
> Show current browsing query
> Execute queries on Enter and insert new line with Shift+Enter. To make this permanent, view settings.
> Switch to dark theme
> Storage engines
> InnoDB Documentation
> Supports transactions, row-level locking, foreign keys and encryption for tables
>
> Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]
>
> ## =====================================
> 2023-06-22 20:29:21 0x27b0 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
>
> ### Per second averages calculated from the last 13 seconds
>
> ### BACKGROUND THREAD
>
> ### srv_master_thread loops: 15 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 6417 srv_idle
> srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 6432
>
> ### SEMAPHORES
>
> ### OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 41
> OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 34
> RW-shared spins 39, rounds 803, OS waits 26
> RW-excl spins 2, rounds 1, OS waits 0
> RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
> Spin rounds per wait: 20.59 RW-shared, 0.50 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
>
> ### LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
>
> 2023-06-22 20:27:38 0x27b0 Error in foreign key constraint of table `assignment1`.`students`:
>
> ### FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
> REFERENCES enrollments (student_id):
> Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
> referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
> in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
> Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
> tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
> cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
> Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/ for correct foreign key definition.
> Alter table `assignment1`.`students` with foreign key constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns near '
> FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
> REFERENCES enrollments (student_id)'.
>
> ### TRANSACTIONS
>
> ### Trx id counter 44
> Purge done for trx's n:o < 44 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
> History list length 18
> LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
> ---TRANSACTION 283841125138576, not started
> 0 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s)
>
> ### FILE I/O
>
> ### I/O thread 0 state: native aio handle (insert buffer thread)
> I/O thread 1 state: native aio handle (log thread)
> I/O thread 2 state: native aio handle (read thread)
> I/O thread 3 state: native aio handle (read thread)
> I/O thread 4 state: native aio handle (read thread)
> I/O thread 5 state: native aio handle (read thread)
> I/O thread 6 state: native aio handle (write thread)
> I/O thread 7 state: native aio handle (write thread)
> I/O thread 8 state: native aio handle (write thread)
> I/O thread 9 state: native aio handle (write thread)
> Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
> ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
> Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
> 181 OS file reads, 409 OS file writes, 136 OS fsyncs
> 0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
>
> ### INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
>
> ### Ibuf: size 1, free list len 0, seg size 2, 0 merges
> merged operations:
> insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
> discarded operations:
> insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> Hash table size 4441, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
> 0.00 hash searches/s, 3.92 non-hash searches/s
>
> ### LOG
>
> ### Log sequence number 75829
> Log flushed up to 75829
> Pages flushed up to 75829
> Last checkpoint at 75820
> 0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
> 90 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
>
> ### BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
>
> ### Total large memory allocated 33554432
> Dictionary memory allocated 30048
> Buffer pool size 1003
> Free buffers 747
> Database pages 256
> Old database pages 0
> Modified db pages 0
> Percent of dirty pages(LRU & free pages): 0.000
> Max dirty pages percent: 75.000
> Pending reads 0
> Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
> Pages made young 0, not young 0
> 0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
> Pages read 169, created 180, written 301
> 0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
> Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
> Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
> LRU len: 256, unzip_LRU len: 0
> I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
>
> ### ROW OPERATIONS
>
> ### 0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
> 0 read views open inside InnoDB
> Process ID=21176, Main thread ID=17500, state: sleeping
> Number of rows inserted 10, updated 2, deleted 0, read 27
> 0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
> Number of system rows inserted 0, updated 0, deleted 0, read 0
> 0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
>
> ## END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have relationship between students and enrollments backwards.

```
ALTER TABLE enrollments
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student_enrollment
FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES students (student_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your FK is on the wrong table. An FK references the PK on another table, so you want the FK on the enrolments table referencing the student table

Comment: Kindly correct the above query ?

Comment: What don’t you understand?